# A curious question about holomorphicity

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

Holomorphic functions don't necessarily have antiderivatives/primitives. For example, $\frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic on the punctured plane $V:=  \mathbb{C}- \{ 0\},$ but it does not have any antiderivative on this domain. My guess (intuition) is that every holomorphic function on the punctured plane $V$ has this "bad" part $\frac{1}{z}$, maybe a multiple of $\frac{1}{z}.$ If we can eliminate this bad portion from the given holomorphic function, the remaining portion might have antiderivative. Is my guess true? My question is rewritten as the following:

If $f: V \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}$ is analytic, then does there exists an analytic function  $g: V \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}$ that has antiderivative such that $ f(z) - g(z) = \alpha \frac{1}{z}$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ ? This is just my guess. I might be totally wrong. Could you help me with some explnation or counter examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. By [Laurent's theorem](https://www.math.utsc.utoronto.ca/c34/chap6.pdf), there are numbers $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb Z}$ such that, for every $z\in V$, $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$. And $f(z)-\frac{a_1}z$ has an antiderivative, which is$$\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{-1\}}\frac{a_n}{n+1}z^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Wow! That's simple, elegant, and amazing. Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.